# Get specific object.value from list of objects kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, filter

I have an entity

```
 data class Account (accountId, username, password, active, date...)
```

Now i have a list of accounts and i want to get the accountId of the account that has active = 1 (The specifications of the app ensures that there is only one account with active = 1)
I tried to map the accounts with active = 1 and then i should get the accountId of the only one returned...

```
 val activeId = accounts.map { accountDto -> accountDto.active = 1 }[0].accountId
```

This should work but it doesn t. How can i do it efficiently??

Comment: what are you getting in return for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `accounts.find { it.active == 1 }?.accountId`

Answer (score 2):

use filter to get the account with active == 1

Comment: its true...i had to use filter instead of map. Thnx